# boolean has different values depending on the thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a multi threading application in c++ in which I create an instance of a class and in it there is a boolean which I set to 'false'.

The case is, when in another thread I try to access this instance and get the boolean, it does not has the value 'false', instead of it, it has a random int value, like 62, ...

What is going on?

Comment: Hi, it's better if you post a [minimal example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your problem.

Comment: Without a reasonable code example, one can only speculate. I suggest that you examine the address of the boolean from each thread, rather than the contents of it -- you might find that your threads are accessing the value from different places, meaning you have no reason to expect them to be identical.

Comment: Is the boolean set to `false` before you launch the other thread, or after? And if after, is the access synchronised? If "after and not synchronised," then that's a problem: there's no guarantee an unsynchronised write will be visible to other threads in any finite amount of time. Multithreading needs synchronisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it was uninitialized initially? Then your another thread sees old cached value because even `bool` should be synchronized between threads.

Comment: "maybe" and "Post Your Answer" do not mix. If it's "maybe" then "add comment" is reasonable while posting as an answer is not.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: I feel this could be. I have tried to remove the initialization of the boolean from the creator and put it instead in setter, and is working right now. How can that be?